# Cannot display multiple queries on the same page

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I've recently began learning Prepared Statements and have started configuring my scripts with the new style.

However, I ran into a little wall and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction?

Here is my SQL query structure:

```
$query = "SELECT `results`, `Success`, `Failure`, `Counter`, `Grades`, `Classes`,
`Special_Id`, `SpecialCondition` FROM `Courses` INNER JOIN `Students` ON `id` = 
`Students_Id` JOIN `Conditions` ON `id` = `Special_Id`";

$stmt = $Mconn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_result($results, $success, $failed, $counter, $grades, $classes,
$specialId, $specialcondition);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
```

And here is one code block:

```
<?php

echo "<select = \"SpecialConditions\">";
if($stmt->num_rows == NULL){
  echo "No results found.";
}else{
  while($stmt->fetch()){

   echo "<option value=\"$specialId\">$specialcondition</option>";
}
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

And another code block:

```
<?php
echo "<select = \"Grades\">";
if($stmt->num_rows == NULL){
  echo "No results found.";
}else{
  while($stmt->fetch()){

      echo "<option value=\"".$grades."\">".$grades."</option>";
  }
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

Ok, now what's happening is if I place both of these queries on the same page, the first block will kill the second one and another query below it and I can't figure out why and I've researched this to no end.

I've tried closing the connection within the same code block thinking that might do the trick but to no prevail.

Now, I do know that the DB connection is working and I do know that the returned results are actually being stored because if I test each block on a separate page, it works as it's supposed to.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice, I got it to work finally. Everything needs to be stored in an array and extracted through that it seems. At least that's the only way I got it to work properly.

Here's the final solution in case anyone is curious or hits this wall in the future. If you know of a way that does not require this method, please let me know.

My Dynamic function that connects and queries the database:

```
<?php

function DB_Query(){
$databasefields = array();
$results = array();

@$Mconn = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPWRD, DBNAME);

   if (!@mysqli_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPWRD, DBNAME)){
     die(DBERROR);
   }

$query = "SELECT `results`, `Success`, `Failure`, `Counter`, `Grades`, `Classes`,
`Special_Id`, `SpecialCondition` FROM `Courses` INNER JOIN `Students` ON `id` =
`Students_Id` JOIN `Conditions` ON `id` = `Special_Id`";

$stmt = $Mconn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

while($field = $meta->fetch_field()){
$databasefields[] = &$row[$field->name];
}

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $databasefields);
while($stmt->fetch()){
  $queried = array();
  foreach($row as $key => $vector){
       $queried[$key] = $vector;
  }

  $results[] = $queried;
}

 return $results;
}

$results = DB_Query();  // placed in DB include file
?>
```

And here's the code I use to actually display the data singly or in multiple blocks. Just change the field name to correspond to yours. The function is dynamic and doesn't require you to hard-code any binding results so you can fetch as many fields as desired.

```
<?php
foreach($results as $row){
echo $row['grades'].'<br />';
}
```

Thanks for all the help and I hope this serves to help those that ran into the same problem as I did.

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able to, please mark your answer as 'accepted' using the checkmark to the left.  This will let others know that your problem is solved.  Cheers~

Answer (score 4):

You have to [close the statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php) when you're done with them

```
$stmt->close();
```

You cannot start another prepared statement while another one is still outstanding, even if you have fetched all of its data.

Comment: Hi Marc, I tried what you suggested and I still cannot display more than one query on the same page. So I tried to place it in both blocks but when I placed $stmt->close(); in both blocks, I received the following error: Warning: mysqli_stmt::close() [mysqli-stmt.close]: Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt

Comment: Did you do the ->close() call inside the fetch loop? It should only be done after the fetch loop completes and you're done retrieving.

Comment: Hi Marc, no I placed it immediately following the </select> tag as well as tried placing it between the two }} just before the final </select> tag and nothing seems to work. I know the results are positive, I just can't get them to display for some reason.